# Input Text doesn't print while using print window

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I have following code

```js
function printDiv(divName) {
  var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
  var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

  document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

  window.print();

  document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}

function sync() {
  var n1 = document.getElementById('n1');
  var n2 = document.getElementById('n2');
  n2.value = n1.value;
}
```

```css
@page {
  size: auto;
  margin: 0mm;
}

@media print {
  #print {
    display: block
  }
  ;
}
```

```html
<div id="printableArea">
  <label id="l1">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="n1" id="n1" onkeyup="sync()">
  <input type="text" name="n2" id="n2" />

</div>
<input type="button" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" value="Print!" class="button" />
```

When i try to print values in the text box, only the blank page will be displayed but the predefined text (here the date field) of the input field of the same form is printed as usual.

How I need to change the javascript function so that it will print the text of input fields also is there any method to print values in the textbox?

Comment: I test your code, but it does not print anything even the text field.

Comment: why this `body {display:none};`? if you add it in `@media print` it will not print anything in `body`. You should remove it and only hide anything that you don't want it to be printed.

Comment: i have removed body {display:none}; but values in text box doesn't print

Comment: There are two closing `body` tags. Remove `</body>` before `</div>`

Comment: Phani, I have removed it still not working

Answer (score 1):

You need to change DOM attribute value:

```
<input type="text" onchange="this.setAttribute('value', this.value)" style="border: none transparent;outline: none;" value="" >
```

Answer (score 0):

The property .innerHtml wont serialize any form or read any input value. Actually the input value is a DOM attribute and has nothing to do with HTML.

If you want to read input values, one of the ways is to read it explicitly.

```
function printDiv() {
 const n1 = document.querySelector("#n1").value;
  const n2 = document.querySelector("#n2").value;
 const content = `N1 : ${n1} <br/>N2 : ${n2}`
 document.body.innerHTML = content;

 window.print();

 document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
 }
```

If you want to use any form serializer, than you might want to check this out : https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-serialize

Eg :

```
const form = document.querySelector("#person");
const data = serialize(form);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is actually nothing going wrong with your code.

First thing you try to hide body content during printing at

```
@media print {
body {display:none};
}
```

That is why it does not show anything during printing.

Second thing, `function printDiv()` is not necessary to have since browser will do that job print content for you already. To call browser to print on click button you just include `<input type="button" onclick="window.print();"  value="Print!" class="button" />` that's it.

Therefore, your code should be look like this:

```
   <html>
    <title>gg</title>
    <style>
    @page { size: auto;  margin: 0mm; }
    @media print {
    /*body {display:none};*/
    }
    </style>
    <script>
    /* Removed */
    // function printDiv() {
    //  var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
    //  var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

    //  document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

    //  window.print();

    //  document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
    //  }
     </script>
     <body>
     <script>
     function sync()
     {
     var n1 = document.getElementById('n1');
     var n2 = document.getElementById('n2');
     n2.value = n1.value;
     }
    </script>
    <div id="printableArea">
    <label id="l1">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="n1" id="n1" onkeyup="sync()">
    <input type="text" name="n2" id="n2"/> 
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="window.print();"  value="Print!" 
    class="button" />
    </body>
     </html>
```

Hope it helps, and let me know if you need anything more. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!! when using window.print(); command hole html page will be print,with the button tag,  but i need to print without button tag.

Comment: @ThishathriFernando, sure it is, so what text would you like to be printed?

Comment: i need to print only the n1 and n2 values and label which are in html code block. i don't need to print the print button with other values

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>code</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function print(divId) {
            var content = document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML;
            var mywindow = window.open('', 'Print', 'height=600,width=800');

            mywindow.document.write('<html><body>');
            mywindow.document.write(content);
            mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

            mywindow.document.close();
            mywindow.focus();
            mywindow.print();
            mywindow.close();
            return true;
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function alm() {
            var typed = document.getElementById("inval").value;
            document.getElementById("outval").innerHTML = typed;
            document.getElementById("outval2").innerHTML=typed;
        }
    </script>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div id="ppp">

        <div id='outval'></div>
        <br>
        <h1>hi hi</h1>
        <div id='outval2'></div>
        <br>


    </div>
    <input type='text' id='inval' onkeyup="alm()">
    <br/>
    <input type="button"  value="click" onclick="print('ppp');">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem but now i cant print more than two pages. The printable file should be 3 pages, but it cuts off at the end of the second page.Any ideas? 
Here's my isssue
[window.print() issue in angularJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46574020/window-print-issue-in-angularjs)