# window.print() issue in angularJs

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

before you start referring me to relevant pages, let me start by saying i have checked out almost every question regarding this topic. I have a form that i want to print using the window.priint() function. Nothing fancy, just a few pages of data. The problem is, i cannot get it to show more than 2 printable pages. (formatted for easier reading)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Intake Form</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a routerLink="/intake">Create a New Case File</a></li>
            <li><a routerLink="/opencases">Open Cases</a></li>
            <li><a routerLink="/closedcases">Closed Cases</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

            <li><a routerLink="/dashboard">Back to Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a (click)="onLogout()" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Logout</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
</nav>

<header id="header">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-
hidden="true"></span>Telephonic Intake<small></small></h1>

        </div>

        <div class="Well">
            <h4> % of Open Cases</h4>
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
                    <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h4> % of Closed Cases</h4>
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%;">
                    <span class="sr-only">70% Complete</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading main-color-bg">
                <h3 class="panel-title">New Process Note</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body" id="printSection">
                <!--To Add Intake Form Below-->

                <div class="container padding-top-10p">
                    <!--Creating Form Panel-->
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">Confidential when Completed</div>
                        <div class="panel-body"></div>
                        <!--Form Content-->
                        <h1>1: Child Abuse Telephonic Intake</h1>
                        <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">

                            <!--Form CSS Styling-->

                            Name:
                            <br>
                            <input type="text" name="Name" ngModel required>
                            <br>
                            <br> Time:
                            <br>
                            <input type="time" name="Time" ngModel required>
                            <br>
                            <br> Call Taken By:
                            <br>
                            <input type="text" name="CallTakenBy" ngModel required>
                            <br>
                            <br> Referred By:
                            <br>
                            <input type="text" name="ReferredBy" ngModel required>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <h2>Details of Child(ren)</h2>
                            <br>
                            <br> Forename:
                            <br>
                            <input type="text" name="ChildName" ngModel required>
                            <br>
                            <br> Surname:
                            <br>
                            <input type="text" name="ChildSurname" ngModel required>
                            <br>
                            <br> Age:
                            <br>
                            <input type="text" name="ChildAge" ngModel required>
                            <br>
                            <br> Gender:
                            <br>
                            <input type="text" name="ChildGender" ngModel required>
                            <br>
                            <br> School:
                            <br>
                            <input type="text" name="ChildSchool" ngModel required>
                            <br>
                            <br> Address:
                            <br>
                            <input type="text" name="ChildAddress" ngModel required>
                            <br>
                            <br> Telephone Number:
                            <br>
                            <input type="text" name="ChildTel" ngModel required>
                            <br>
                            <br>

                            <h2>Details of Parent or Caregiver</h2>
                            <br>
                            <br> Name of Parent (Mother):
                            <br>
                            <input type="text" name="MotherName" ngModel required>
                            <br>
                            <br> Name of Parent (Father):
                            <br>
                            <input type="text" name="FatherName" ngModel required>
                            <br>
                            <br> Contact Number Home(Mother):
                            <br>
                            <input type="number" name="MotherContactHomeTel" ngModel required>
                            <br>
                            <br> Contact Number Home(Father):
                            <br>
                            <input type="number" name="FatherContactHomeTel" ngModel required>
                            <br>
                            <br> Contact Number Work(Mother):
                            <br>
                            <input type="number" name="MotherContactWorkTel" ngModel required>
                            <br>
                            <br> Contact Number Work(Father):
                            <br>
                            <input type="number" name="FatherContactWorkTel" ngModel required>
                            <br>
                            <br> Address:
                            <br>
                            <input type="text" name="ParentAddress" ngModel required>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <h2> Details of Abuse</h2>
                            <br> Type of Abuse:
                            <br>
                            <input type="text" name="TypeOfAbuse" ngModel required>
                            <br>
                            <br> Prepetrator:
                            <br>
                            <input type="text" name="Perpetrator" ngModel required>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <title>Case Details:</title>
                            <br>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Case Details">Case Details:</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="Case Details" name="CaseDetails" ngModel required></textarea>
                                <br>
                                <br> Worker Referred to:
                                <br>
                                <input type="text" name="WorkerReferredTo" ngModel required>
                                <br>
                                <br>

                                <div>
                                    <!--Buttons-->
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="window.print()">Print</button>

                                        <button [disabled]="!f.valid" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
</section>
```

If i paste that in codepen.io, it prints everything.
If i use in my angular app, it cuts off after the second page.

Comment: Please fix your formatting. Can you provide the codepen?

Comment: You used the wrong angular tag. AngularJS is for 1.x. Angular is for 2+. But this is going to be a CSS issue anyway, not angular.

Comment: @Jamie.. it is edited, you can now post it in codepen. But if you generate a new component in angular and paste it there, it doesn't print all the pages